# $S^3$ viewed as a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^2$ and the solid torus, embedding

Tags: general-topology, low-dimensional-topology

Consider the 3-sphere $S^3$ viewed as a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^2$:
$$S^3=\{(u,v):u,v\in\mathbb{C}, |u|^2+|v|^2=1\}.$$
Inside the sphere we consider 
$$A:=\{(u,v)\in S^3: |v|=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\}.$$
I already showed that $S^3\setminus A$ has two connected components, namely 
$$X_1=\{(u,v):|u|<|v|\}, X_2=\{ (u,v): |u|>|v|\}.$$
I also showed that the two connected components satisfy:
$$\bar{X}_1 \cap \bar{X}_2 = \delta(X_1) = \delta (X_2) = A.$$
with $\delta$ the boundary. all these closures and boundaries are inside the space $S^3$.

Now consider the unit circle and the closed unit disk
$$S^1=\{(\alpha,\beta)\in\mathbb{R}^2: \alpha^2 + \beta^2 = 1\}, D^2=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2\leq 1\}.$$
By a solid torus we mean any space homeomorphic to $S^1\times D^2$.

I have to show that 
$$f: S^1\times D^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3, f((\alpha,\beta),(x,y))=((2-x)\alpha,(2-x)\beta,y)$$
is an embedding. 
Then I have to show that $\bar{X}_i$ is a solid torus for $i\in\{1,2\}$.

How should I do this?

Thanks!